# One ip on port 80 with mutiable vhost different names and ports

Tags: port, virtualhost

I'm unsure of how to ask or describe in words what I'm trying to do, or if it can be done this way, so I decided to draw a diagram. Hopefully its fairly self explanatory:

[image: Diagram of what im trying to do]

I know I can do Named based virtual hosts all on Port 80, but can I place them on different ports and have the server work out what named host is which and which port they are on?

---

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/foo-1.com
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/foo-1.com/>
        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/foo-2.com
    ServerName foo-2.com
    <Directory "/var/www/foo-2.com">
        allow from all
        Options -Indexes
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use standard vhosts ?

Comment: Why are the VHosts on port 8080 and 8081, respectively?  What is port 80 doing, then?  Is there a proxy in here somewhere, or is Apache acting as one?

Comment: For some reason if i create to vhost on 80 with different names only one works correct, meaning one will work typing foo-1.com or www.foo-1.com but the other vhost will ony work typing "foo-2.com" but typing www.foo-2.com will redirect to foo-1.com.

Comment: I only used those ports as examples I was thinking of using apache as a proxy but was unsure of what or how to go about this or where to look.

Comment: So, rather than solve what is quite possibly an easy problem you invent some weird scheme ... Show is your vhost configuration

Comment: I suppose if thats what it is. But at any rate what would cause the server to do what its doing as i described  in the comment above?

Comment: Well not shure how I should post the vhost config on here. but here it is: 
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
 ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /var/www/foo-1.com
 <Directory />
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
 </Directory>
<Directory /var/www/foo-1.com/>
  Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride None
  Order allow,deny
  allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/foo-2.com
ServerName foo-2.com
<Directory "/var/www/foo-2.com">
allow from all
Options -Indexes
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

Comment: You can edit your own or anyone else's posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have two [name based virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html) working on the same IP address try something like this

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost _*:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName foo-1.com
    ServerAlias www.foo1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/foo-1.com
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/foo-1.com/>
        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/foo-2.com
    ServerName foo-2.com
    ServerAlias www.foo-2.com
    <Directory "/var/www/foo-2.com">
        allow from all
        Options -Indexes
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Note that each vhost has a [ServerName](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#servername) and [ServerAlias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serveralias)

Comment: Thank you much that worked great! appreciate all the help.

Comment: This is the better way to go rather than my other suggestion of using rewrites.  What you ask is possible, but not a standard approach.

Comment: I have my server using the method described above as im not trying to do make things more complex than need be or reinvent the wheel or anything. Ive tryed other solutions similar to problem made in  the comments above with no avail so thought maybe i needed to go about this a different way. However im still somewhat new to apache and the configuration part. And as always i try to do as much research and testing as possible before asking anything and I'll try to ask questions more specific to the actual problem in the future. But I do appreciate all the help from the community. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

On first reading your scenario, my first response was why would you want to do it this way much like the others, but with Apache or PHP something like this is possible.  You would be much better off getting virtual hosts to work properly on port 80 as this is what web site visitors expect, but this is my opinion.

To do what you'd like to accomplish, there are two options and you have to be comfortable that an HTTP redirect has to happen.  No way around that one.

Your first option is to use PHP for this with something as follows...

1. Your main Apache site would cover all default site requests using PHP
2. PHP would read the headers, look at the URL and pass back a redirect to the browser
3. The browser would then redirect to the correct URL

Apache supports a rewrite option as well and you could organize this for each site in the following manner

```
# First host rewrite
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.\foo-1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.foo-1.com:8080/$1 [L,R=301]

# Second host rewrite
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.\foo-2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.foo-2.com:8081/$1 [L,R=301]
```

However, if you are going to go to this level with rewrite conditions, it may be easier to figure out VHOSTS in Apache and get it working properly on your server.

Comment: Ok so it can be done then and that is really what I was after. If only out of pure curiosity if something like that could be done. I have several domain names and only one server and one ip using noip as my dns. and may not always want all servers running on port 80 for any number of various reasons.